# Why is positioning an item on the css grid done by grid-line and not row/column number?

Tags: css, css-grid

I gave a tech presentation at my company about the new CSS grid spec and my manager asked me a very interesting question for which I didn't have a simple answer. Why, when positioning an element within a grid, are positions referred to by what grid-lines they are between instead of having some inherent way of identifying the columns and rows? I know about grid-template-areas, but that is still something you have to define yourself.

Essentially, my question is this:
Why are the numbers in the following example referring to grid line numbers instead of grid column numbers?

```
grid-column: 1/4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid lines define a clear start and end point for placing grid items and defining grid areas.

Saying that a grid item should start at grid line 1 and end at grid line 4 makes it clear that the item should be contained within the area *between* those lines. Saying that a grid item should start at column 1 and end at column 4 is a little less clear: Should the item occupy column 4 or not? If it doesn't, then it would be possible to place another item at column 4 with `grid-column: 4` following the same semantics. Otherwise, placing an item there would cause it to overlap with the first item.

This is particularly important for auto-placement, which can result in *new* rows and columns being created if there is no room in the explicit grid to place additional items. [Section 8.5 of the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#auto-placement-algo) contains all the details.

Comment: But as with anything in front-end development, if there's a standard that browser-makers can agree upon, we'll follow it. Questions like "Should the item occupy column 4 or not?" would naturally be resolved by such a standard. My question is asking why is it NOT the standard?

Comment: @soultrust: In hindsight I probably shouldn't be trying to infer design decisions based on what is in the spec alone. I don't know if any of the editors of the original spec are still working on the current one, but I'll try to get in touch with someone.

Answer (score 0):

The [**CSS Grid specification**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) defines multiple ways to align and position items in a grid container. They are described in the section named [**Placing Grid Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement).

With regard to your question:

> Why are the numbers in the following example referring to grid line numbers instead of grid column numbers?
>
> ```
> grid-column: 1 / 4;
> ```

Because that particular method of placing grid items is call **"Line-based Placement"**, which focuses on the boundary lines of a grid area.

> [**Line-based
>   Placement**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)
>
> The `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and
>   `grid-column-end` properties determine a grid item’s size and location
>   within the grid by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic)
>   to its grid placement, thereby specifying the inline-start,
>   block-start, inline-end, and block-end edges of its grid area.

*("inline-start" is the side where text begins. It's the left side in LTR. "block-start" is the top in horizontal writing mode. "-end" refers to the opposite side. [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/#logical-directions))*

If you wanted your rule to count columns / rows instead of lines, then use the `span` keyword.

Whereas:

```
grid-column: 1 / 4
```

creates a grid area starting at column line 1 and ending at column line 4 (i.e., columns 1, 2 & 3)...

```
grid-column: 1 / span 3
```

does the same thing, but counts the columns.

There are other methods available. See the descriptions here:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement

Here's a demo of the two methods described above:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 75px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
section {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section><code>grid-column: 1 / 4<br>counts lines</code></section>
  <section><code>grid-column: 1 / span 3<br>counts columns</code></section>
  <section>3</section>
  <section>4</section>
  <section>5</section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. Here's a simple representation of a grid (taken from https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-css-grid-layout):

[image: A simple 3 x 3 grid]

As we know, a column spanning the middle and last columns can be referenced by start and end line numbers:

```
grid-column: 2 / 4;
```

But there's really no intrinsic reason why the spec couldn't have allowed us to specify *column numbers* instead:

```
 grid-column: 2 / 3;
```

The following methods would still have worked, exactly as they do now:

```
 grid-column: 2 / -1;

 grid-column: 2 / span 2;
```

So those alternate methods are not an argument for line-based referencing. The difference between numbering grid *lines* vs grid *tracks* (rows and columns) is really only apparent when you try to reference that last row or column from your starting point—a classic off-by-one error!

So why did the W3C choose lines over tracks? Did they toss a coin?

The answer can be found [here, in *The Story of CSS Grid, from Its Creators*](https://alistapart.com/article/the-story-of-css-grid-from-its-creators/), a 2017 article on A List Apart.

> Peter Linss, then Co-Chair of the CSS Working Group, also suggested
> that they incorporate the concept of grid lines in the spec (instead
> of only talking about tracks). He believed including this familiar
> graphic design concept would make the spec more accessible to
> designers.
>
> “When we were thinking initially about CSS Grid, we were thinking
> about it in a very app-centric model,” recalled Microsoft’s Rossen
> Atanassov, who is also an Editor on the spec. “But grid is nothing
> new. I mean, grid’s been here for a very long time. And that
> traditional type of grid has always been based on lines. And we’d been
> kind of ignoring the lines. When we realized that we could marry the
> two implementations—the app side and the typography side of the
> Grid—this for me, personally, was one of those aha moments that really
> inspired me to continue working on Grid.”

So there you have it! It was all about making it easy for those old-time graphic designers, who as we all know, aren't smart enough to adapt to a slightly new concept. ;-)

As an old-time graphic designer *myself*, I actually find this a bit odd, as I have never thought about a layout grid in terms of line numbers, and if you'd asked me which was the more intuitive approach, I'd have probably sided with your boss. And as a programmer, I find the choice of one-based addressing (instead of [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)) to refer to the grid lines as, well a bit odd. But hey, it's a minor adjustment to one's way of thinking, and one I'm happy to make to enjoy all the layout goodness that CSS grid brings us.